# Recommended Way to do Frameset in HTML5

Tags: html, frame, frameset

I'm trying to create a page in ASP.NET MVC that has my site's content in the top and another site's content in the bottom. An example of what I mean can be see at http://freewebfiles.com/Site.aspx?url=http://www.soundfilesonline.com.

However, that site uses frameset and `<frame>` tags. And my understanding is that these constructs are now deprecated, if not simply obsolete.

So what is the recommended way to do this now, which pretty much means how should I do it in HTML5?

*For added points, if I can get this working, does anyone know how to make the site that appears in the bottom frame the active site?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<frame>` is obsolete in HTML 5, but an `<iframe>` isn't. You can put an `iframe` inside a carefully designed `div` to get more or less the same effect.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to "carefully design" my `<div>`s but have not figured it out yet. I've reposted what I have in [another stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679160/styling-iframes).

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same thing using an `<iframe>` inside a `<div>` object. For resizing effect, you can use a splitter: http://methvin.com/splitter/ or http://krikus.com/js/splitter/

Comment: Thanks, but the page I'm trying to emulate doesn't require any scripting. I was hoping my approach would be that simple.