# Styling iframes

Tags: css, html, iframe

I'm trying to display two websites on an ASP.NET MVC page. The first website should appear in the upper 130 or so pixels, and the second website should use up all remaining vertical space. Both websites should use up the entire width of the browser.

There is an example of what I want [here](http://freewebfiles.com/Site.aspx?url=http://www.soundfilesonline.com), but it uses a frameset with `<frame>` tags, which are now [deprecated](http://paulwallas.com/html5-obsolete-and-deprecated-elements/).

So I've started a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUZeg/) to try and arrange two `<iframe>` tags instead. I've got most of it but am unable to have the second website use up all the remaining vertical space. (I would prefer not to use jQuery unless it's absolutely necessary.)

Does anyone know the missing piece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting an absolute position for the content frame you are able to position it 130px from the top, which is the height of your header. Then also set it to 0 from the bottom. This produces the effect of stretching it to fill the remaining height of the viewport.

```
#contentdiv {
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;bottom:0;
}
#contentframe {width: 100%;height:100%;
}
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bAfBs/

Comment: Thanks, that's close, but it looks like it makes the bottom iframe the entire height of the browser window, creating a secondary scroll bar. It doesn't subtract the vertical space taken by the top iframe.

Comment: updated the answer... using overflow:hidden removes the document scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the problem. There's no way to scroll to the bottom of the website in the second iframe. Some other technique is needed to limit the height of this iframe to 100% less the height of the first iframe.